# Resize UIImageView after finish drawing

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to draw line in my app. First i set the drawing window size as my view size. After finish drawing, i want to resize the UIImageView so that there's no empty spaces around the drawing. Is there an option to auto resize the UIImageView like sizeToFit in UILabel?

```
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.vwDesktop.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.vwDesktop.frame.size.width, self.vwDesktop.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    drawImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, is it the `contentMode` property on `UIView` (and hence `UIImageView` that you want?  This will determine how the image is sized to fit the view.

As an aside, you don't need to call `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` in each of your Core Graphics functions.  Why not just save the context in a local variable:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

and use that `CGContextRef` each time you need to refer to the current context?

However, it looks to me that you could just do all of this inside a `UIView`'s `drawRect` method without  having to deal with creating an image context, unless for some reason you want to keep the `UIImage` of the line that you are drawing.

Comment: ok. i will save the context in a local variable. what i'm doing is to allow user to draw something on the screen then after that i will insert into an array. my array consist of a a lot of images (photo, user drawn, stamps). so currently the drawing's UIImageView consist of some transparent border, which i don't want it as it will affect my selection of which view i want to edit.